# How to Create a IOS Share Extension that works with a Cordova App?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a working and published Phonegap/ Cordova app.

I need you to build a Share Extension for the app.

The Share extension will accept a set of images (from the Photos /Mail / Whatsapp / Line / .. other apps via the Share button).

Upon share, it will open up a form (existing Cordova/PhoneGap) in the app where extra information about the upload will be asked and the images submitted.

This should only support iOS.

We have an ionic/PhoneGap/Cordova app built for iOS. We need to create a Share extension for iOS.

The Share Extension will register itself for image file types.

Please give any solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Did you find any solution?